# How can I add apostrophe inside an array from a form's textarea

Tags: php, arrays, trim, explode

The below code works fine.

```
$numbers = array('0018182225252','0012524578125','0015458525458');
$message = $_POST['message'];
$pnum = $numbers;
```

However, how can I achieve the a similar code given that the values will come from a textarea per line.

0018182225252
0012524578125
0015458525458

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="1" id="numbr" name="numbr" wrap="physical"></textarea>
```

I have tried my luck using explode but I think I'm having conflict with the apostrophe so it doesn't work..

```
$num1 = $_POST['numbr'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$pnum = explode(",", $num1);
$numbers = array($pnum);
```

no luck. thanks in advance guys!

Comment: If the numbers are one per line, why are you using a comma as the delimiter instead of `\n`?

Comment: Hello man, I'm in the assumption that using comma will give me a result of $var = array('line1','line2'); which is what i needed for the code to work. any thoughts? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) works by splitting a string from a given delimiter. For example, if you have a string `$s = 'a,b,c'`, using `explode( ',', $s )` gives `array( 'a', 'b', 'c' )`. If you have string `$s = 'a;b;c'`, then you'd use `explode( ';', $s )` and so on.

So if you have a string of numbers separated by a newline, you'd use the newline character (`\n`) as the delimiter:

```
$numbers = explode( "\n", $_POST[ 'numbr' ] );
```

Note that `explode()` returns an array so you don't have to put the result into another array afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
explode(",", $num1);

with

explode("/r", $num1);
```

$numbers = $pnum; ( remove the array()

Comment: Thanks for the reply Grumpy. I was able to see result, but I need to put the apostrophe per value inside the array, the current result is this: Array ( [0] => 011639178717229 011639306237777 ) I need to have it like the above code.. '0018182225252','0012524578125','0015458525458' as it was the only format being accepted.. any thoughts?

Comment: You need `\n` instead of `/r`.